# How to select a element value if the element is not visible in Inspect Element window?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

Please anyone can help me how to select a element value if the element is not visible in Inspect Element window while automation with PAF.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the example code to fetch the value:

```
<highlight css="$prop{VariableNameInputBox}" />
<click css="$prop{VariableNameInputBox}" />
<specialKeys specialChar="{control}+a+c" css="$prop{VariableNameInputBox}"  />
<clipboard varName="varName" />
```

We can use the value by ${varName} anywhere in our scripts.